# save input file (more than one file) into array var js,jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**html Markup:**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="fileSelect" type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload!" onclick='showFileModified();' />
</form>
```

**Script:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function showFileModified()
{
    var input, file;

    input = document.getElementById( 'fileSelect' );

        file = input.files[0];

        file.lastModifiedDate;
        alert(file.lastModifiedDate);
}
</script>
```

If i select more than one file lets say 4 files. i want each file modified date `alert(file.lastModifiedDate)`. how can i use array here to achieve this.

**what i tried:**

```
function showFileModified()
{
        var input[], file;

        input = document.getElementById( 'fileSelect' );

        for(var i=0; i<=input.length; i++)
        {
            alert('d');
            file = input.files[i];

            file.lastModifiedDate;
            alert(file.lastModifiedDate);

       }
}
```

Comment: `input.files` is your array. shouldn't you check it's length rather than `input`?

Comment: if i select 3 files from input, isn't it save it in input rather than file?

Comment: This line: `for(var i=0; i<=input.length; i++)` `input.length` makes no sense. You only have one input, which you selected by id, it doesn't have a length.

Comment: what should i do then? how do i make the for loop right?

Comment: uhmmm.... use the length of the input.files array instead? You know, the array you're iterating over?

Comment: i am trying. if it works i will let you know.

Comment: that's the thing i am not getting it. i need to iterate the for loop depends on the number of files being selected. that's why i was using input.length but as you said it doesn't make any sense to use input.length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this to get all modified date values:

```
function showFileModified(){
    var input = document.getElementById( 'fileSelect' );
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i){
        alert(input.files[i].lastModifiedDate);
    }      
}
```

input.files is an array with all selected files listed. That's why you need to loop through this array *(which is achieved by looping from 0 to array.length - 1)*

But you should take care using multiple ids for a single tag as well as you should not use names with special characters:

```
<input id="fileSelect" type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*"/>
```

Better use something like this (you would not even need to use a **name**:

```
<input id="fileSelect" type="file" name="fileSelector" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
```